# I have a variable with PIC S9(4). Whether I use COMP or COMP-3 here?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I know COMP will take 2 bytes and COMP-3 will take 3 bytes of size.
The field will undergo lot of computations. What should I use here?

The field involves only addition and subtraction with another thirty PIC S9(4) variables, for which also I need to decide the usage clauses need to be used.

Comment: What is involved in all these computations? Literals? Other fields? What type of other fields?

Comment: Based on the information you gave, COMP.  The computations should take less code and less time.  The smaller field size is a bonus.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc that may not be the case if the binary requires constant conversion to packed-decimal due to other fields.

Comment: @Bill Woodger: Yes, you're correct.  That's why I said, "Based on the information you gave."  As a interesting aside, when I worked for the US Federal Government, our Cobol standard was we could only use COMP and DISPLAY.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc interesting standard :-) Ensures conversion all the time unless everything in a mathematical statement is binary already. Other than the fact that the Federal Govt doesn't pay (the Taxpayer does) I wonder what the reasoning was. Probably thought to be "good" at the time. Perhaps for multiple compilers on different "platforms", although PACKED-DECIMAL instead of COMP-3 would have dealt with that, since the 1985 COBOL Standard.

Comment: You should let us know your compiler/OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of that is platform dependent.  As a general rule, "comp", which is a twos compliment binary is going to be a little faster, and "comp-3" which is packed decimal, is going to be human readable as decimal in memory or on DASD, is easier for humans to work with.

But those rules were laid down in the ages of very slow processors with single pipelines.  Trying to make a decision based on performance is very premature.  Especially for only thirty fields.  On todays hardware, with todays compilers, with caching and speculative execution, there might be no difference that you can ever notice.

If you are really concerned about it, write two small test programs with your intended calculations and the fields defined both ways, then do a comparative performance test on your intended hardware.  My prediction is that you will notice no difference at all.

Mostly though, just write for accuracy and tune later.  It is highly unlikely that you will notice the very fast add/subtract operations when in the context of I/O.

Comment: For integer-only processing, COMP/BINARY is going to be faster even today. Whether by hardware or software, accurate decimals on a binary machine is much slower than plain binary. The rest is very good advice.

Comment: While I do agree, in the context of the overall process, it might just never matter.  Consider modern z/OS hardware, one physical I/O is still slower than many millions of AP or SP instructions.  It's possible that nobody will ever notice the difference.

Comment: Sure, but also if CPU usage is an element of charging, reducing it can still give benefit, even if it is just "waiting for IO faster". The thing which indicates to me that small things matter is the effort IBM have put and are continuing to put into optimisation for V5.x. If every numeric reference is wrong, that can easily be one or more percent added onto the CPU bill. Too many factors to address easily :-)

Comment: Thanks Joe Zitzelberger and @BillWoodger  for all these discussions. I use z/OS hardware and COBOL 4.1 compiler, therefore may not see any differences as per the answers. I will run a test program. Thanks.

Comment: If you get a chance, look at the COBOL 5.x compiler, they have put very serious work into optimization in this iteration.  It might not be an option for you to upgrade, but if it is...